# Ability to Stop or Cancel a NotesView.update?

Tags: dominotogo

Is there a way to stop/cancel a NotesView.update() after it has started?

I've tried putting a return; statement in a progress callback, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Canceling a NotesView synchronization is not that easy, because there are only few possibilities to cancel anything at all :-) 

First an http request is made to retrieve the JSON data. I'm not aware that one can cancel a running HTTP request in Titanium. 
Then the JSON data is being processed on the device - it would be possible to cancel the process at that point. But would that be useful?

Comment: That makes sense. And no, I don't think it would be useful at that point. My use case for this was to have a way for a user to back out of a view update that was taking too long.

Comment: I just looked at the Titanium documentation, there is an abort() function in the HTTPClient - I will check if I can add it to DominoToGo.

Comment: That would be great. Thanks.